# Buffers not close automatically by Vimspector

Tags: buffers, hidden-buffers, plugin-vimspector

I have been using Vimspector for debugging Python but like 8-10 months now, the Python terminal buffer that is opened by Vimspector when the debugger runs, is not automatically closed when the debugger re-starts or exits. This leads to having multiple Python terminal buffers, one for each run of the debugger.

I have tried to run the bare-minimum example of Vimspector and this doesn't happening. Meaning that the Vispector is not to blame. I thought that it was the status line (lightline plugin) that I use, but again the same.

The weird part, which lead me ask here, is that after I restarted my computer (MacOS with M1) the above issue with the buffers didn't happen when I first run the Vimspector. When I closed Vim and reopened it, then the issue came back.

Any help? I'm quite baffled by this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure this question fit the forum. It is presented like a bug either in Vim or in Vimspector. It looks to me that more analysis is needed such that the problem can be reproduced with a minimal vimrc file and addressed to the corresponding GitHub project :-|

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl but it is not an issue of the plugin. With bare minimum vimrc the issue is not there.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Python terminal" in Vim. If your plugin creates those, then it is its responsibility to discard them when they are not needed anymore. Hence… use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: I believe we have not enough information to reproduce your problem. I suppose you should simplify your vimrv file to have a minimum version that has the problem. With that the failing interaction between two plugins can be identified and the correct bug registered :-)

Comment: See if [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) helps at all. Otherwise, I agree that we don't have enough information to reproduce or solve the problem.